# Why re.sub in python adding a space after replacement? How to get rid of the space?

Tags: python, string

```
import re
def transformrec(record):
    new_record = re.sub(r"([\d-]+\,)",r"+1-\1\0", record)
    search_pa=re.search(r"(\,[\d-]+\,)",record)
    #print(search_pa[0])
    #print(search_pa[1])
    print(new_record)

print(transformrec("Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator"))
```

Output

```
O/P : Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309, System Administrator.
```

In this case, there is an additional space after the number 802-867-5309,

Comment: I ran it too, there is no problem in code and giving without space

Comment: Note that `transformrec` doesn't actually return anything.  It just prints `new_record` and returns `None`.  So printing the return value in the caller doesn't make sense.

Comment: `new_record = re.sub(r"([\d-]+\,)",r"+1-\1", record)` has no space it it -remoe the \0 from your replace pattern

Comment: @vish in which python version? python2 and 3 both have the space ... right here: `...309, System...` tested in https://pyfiddle.io/  which prints the space

Comment: If the data is CSV, consider whether handling it with the [`csv` module of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) would be more appropriate than regular expressions.

Comment: @PatrickArtner python3

Comment: I think we're talking about a difference in how your terminal presents the zerobyte when printed (`\0`). On zsh/iterm2/osx there is no space printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a space, it's a `NUL` character. From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `\number`
>
> Matches the contents of the group of the same number. Groups are numbered starting from 1. For example, `(.+) \1` matches `'the the'` or
>   `'55 55'`, but not `'thethe'` (note the space after the group). This
>   special sequence can only be used to match one of the first 99 groups.
>   **If the first digit of number is 0, or number is 3 octal digits long,
>   it will not be interpreted as a group match, but as the character with
>   octal value number**. Inside the '[' and ']' of a character class, all
>   numeric escapes are treated as characters.

You have a `\0` in your replacement which is being interpreted as a `NUL` character. The fix is simply to remove it.

```
new_record = re.sub(r"([\d-]+\,)",r"+1-\1", record)
```

Comment: Thanks, As you said the problem was with \0.

Answer (score 4):

You have a weird reference to `\0`. Remove it:

```
re.sub(r"([\d-]+\,)",r"+1-\1", record)
```

And, as someone already suggested, `return` the new value, do not print it.